# If a wondrous item was dynamically created as slimy, can I remove the smell with prestidigitation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

During dynamic creation of my +1 Body Wrap of Mighty Strikes the item gained the "slimy" characteristic.  Is it possible to remove the putrid smell of the slime with prestidigitation to remove the -2 penalty to Diplomacy and Handle Animal checks due to the smell?  If so, since RAW states that prestidigitation can …

> "clean […] items in a 1-foot cube each round."

Would this continue to cleanse the smell each round for an hour?  OR would it be only an instantaneous effect?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is magical slime.  Magic item properties cannot be modified on the item once it has been created outside of specific circumstances, *prestidigitation* not being one of them.  Slimy is a magic item quirk that says:

> The item is covered in putrid slime, which seeps out to cover the bearer as well. The bearer gains a +5 circumstance bonus on Escape Artist checks, on combat maneuver checks to break grapples, and to CMD against grapples (these bonuses do not stack with grease or other similar effects), but takes a –2 penalty on Acrobatics, Disable Device, and Disguise checks, as well as on Diplomacy and Handle Animal checks except against creatures that aren't bothered by putrid slime. *([Magic Items, PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items))*

Since the nature of this quirk is clearly magical, and prestidigitation "*lacks the power to duplicate any other spell effects,*" ([Paizo PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/prestidigitation.html)) I would argue strongly that prestidigitation also cannot "clean" a magical quirk from a magical item.

Take for example, a pair of muddy boots: they are muddy.  You could wipe them with a cloth and they would be clean.  Pfah, that's too much effort for a mage of my stature, so **poof** -- now my boots are clean by way of *prestidigitation.*

On the other hand, imagine a pair of cursed boots.  The curse is that the boots always appear to be muddy.  Curses, being magical in nature, are a tricky thing to deal with.  You might be able to wipe away the dirt, but because of the curse, they instantly muddy themselves again.  Prestidigitation is no better: you clean them with the spell, but they are instantly dirty again.

Think of the *slimy* quirk as a sort of minor curse -- no matter how much you wipe off that slime, it constantly seeps slime and covers you, the bearer of the slimy object, as it's description says.  You may even be able to cast prestidigitation to clean the slime off once per round but it will always be seeping the slime, unable to be stopped.

Answer (score -1):

Prestidigitation works for 1 hour and lets you clean 1-foot cube each round.
It thus becomes a question of how fast the slime spreads.

It takes quite a few rounds to clear your entire body one cubic foot per round - at least a minute.

The description of the slime-effect does not state how fast the slime spreads exactly, so if it takes a few minutes before you are covered you might be a little better off if you keep wiping it off with Prestidigitation. If it spreads to your entire body in less than a minute, then you can't remove it fast enough to matter.

> Once cast, a prestidigitation spell enables you to perform simple
>   magical effects for 1 hour.

This does not specify what kind of action is needed to perform those tricks in question - it might well be that you need to spend actions to cleaning.

If I were the DM for this I would judge that if you spend a minute cleaning yourself (using magic or otherwise) then you would get a few minutes (3d6?) of not smelling bad, as that seems like a good trade-off and opening for odd roleplaying situations, but that it just me.

I would recommend donning some heavy robes or a coat over that gear and stack on a ton of perfume and try to convince your DM that it masks the smell and offsets the Diplomacy check disadvantage (but might make the other problems worse).

Comment: In playing this character with the item, it seems to be optimal to put this on just when "the music starts building" - hopefully before you hear "role for initiative."  Then to take this off and clean up before social encounters. - Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Or better, make it part of your character concept to be slimy. That or do not wear it at all.